# SMART drive error Lenovo Y580

Tags: lenovo-laptop, smart

I have the same issue as this person, that apparently was never answered for him either.

http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-Z-and-P-series/I-have-problems-diagnosing-if-my-hard-drive-is-failing-or-not/td-p/1102689

I have a Lenovo Y580 with the combo SSD/HDD thing.  Mine is one terabyte his looks like the 750mb.

The disk tools show a SMART error when looking for S/N, but there is a S/N

```
--------------- SeaTools for Windows v1.2.0.10 ---------------
5/17/2014 10:45:30 AM
Model: ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
Serial Number: S2U5J9ACA16694
Firmware Revision: 2AR10001
Short DST - Started 5/17/2014 10:45:29 AM
Short DST - FAIL 5/17/2014 10:45:35 AM
SeaTools Test Code: 6C9AC2A4
Fix All Fast - FAIL 5/17/2014 10:47:20 AM
SeaTools Test Code: 6C9AC2A4
Identify - Started 5/17/2014 10:48:02 AM
Short DST - Started 5/17/2014 10:48:15 AM
Short DST - FAIL 5/17/2014 10:48:23 AM
SeaTools Test Code: 6C9AC2A4
Short DST - Started 5/17/2014 10:50:44 AM
Short DST - FAIL 5/17/2014 10:50:48 AM
SeaTools Test Code: 6C9AC2A4
SMART - FAIL 8/13/2014 7:50:00 PM
SeaTools Test Code: 6C9AC2A4
```

is this due to Lenovo's special combine two drive and make them act like one thing or is this a legit error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have in hands is a damaged system array, the idea behind platter HDD+SSD is to make the SSD as 'boot device' and the HDD as 'shadow'+cache+storage, but the system relies in a faulty Lenovo OEM software for that purposes instead of your chipset manufacturer software

as IT technician i have seen this a couple of times, and every time the best shot is to use the SSD as boot and keep the HDD as storage unit

the standard procedure is doing a clean install in the SSD and then erase the HDD, run a recovery software in order to 'salvage' info on the HDD, later create partition(s) on the HDD and put back the recovered info

i suggest you, if the pc is on warranty, sent it for a checkup, and ask for a backup of your info, since the fault is in the software that came 'by default' with the pc they're in the obligation of doing it

Comment: in this scenario, what is damaged? A physical component or just the way is set up?  Does anything in what i have shown indicate something is actually needing replacement?

Comment: a way it's set up, because a faulty software error your system is having logical issues, by now your hardware still in good condition, since the disk tools recognize them, you should follow what i have indicated before

Comment: I did a reinstall and seems to work okay. will separate the drives and do as you suggested. thanks.